# keystonejs schema function as public function

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

want use a public schema function but dont know how to implement,
here my example:

```
var Token = new keystone.List('Token', {});

Token.add({
    uuid: { type: String, index: true },
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'created, used', default: 'created' },
    endDate: { type: Types.Date },
    user: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
    url: { type: String }
});

Token.schema.methods.getUrl = function () { /*DO something*/ }
```

than i tried to call getUrl in my modul

```
var Token = modelUtils.promisifyModel(keystone.list('Token').model);
Token.getUrl();
```

than i get an error : Token.schema.methods is not a function

Comment: What is modelUtils? it's not clear which code the error is coming from.

Comment: jed i'm so sorry about my laziness, your question was the right basic to find the problem, please see my answer... and thanks a lot for your answer/question.

Comment: no worries, glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry, **modelUtils** is a wrapper around the Token Object, and give some property of the wrapperobject back. i was to lazy to check the whole code (not my code), but if i found the question about **modelUtils** i realized that this is the point to extend the the wrapper class.
I'm realy sorry and feel a little bit a shamed about my laziness.